spring boot deploy war on centos 9 problem
I have three machines: Windows, CentOS 7, and CentOS 9. I have deployed a WAR file successfully on Windows using XAMPP and on CentOS 7 using Tomcat with MariaDB. However, on CentOS 9, the application does not perform auto-migration during the initial deployment.
Here's what I have tried:

Checked Tomcat and MariaDB logs (catalina.out and MariaDB logs), but didn't find any relevant errors.

Verified that the application's configuration files (application.properties, persistence.xml) on CentOS 9 are correctly configured to connect to the MariaDB database.

Tested database connectivity from CentOS 9 using the mysql command-line client, which connects successfully to the MariaDB instance.

Ensured that the database schema required by the application is correctly created in MariaDB.


Despite these steps, the application on CentOS 9 still does not perform auto-migration of the database schema like it does on Windows and CentOS 7.
What could be causing this issue? Are there any additional steps or configurations specific to CentOS 9 that I might be missing? Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I'd be very surprised if it's Centos 9 itself that is the issue, rather than something else that is different between the environments. What JPA implementation are you using? Is it the same in all environments? How are you preforming the schema migration? Using the built-in JPA properties, implementation-specific ones, a third-party library, or custom application code? What specific migration steps are you expecting it to take? It would be helpful to include your persistence.xml in the question. It might be useful to increase the log level as well.
